# How would I write a constructor for my class if there aren't any instance variables?

Tags: java

I want to write a constructor that accepts no arguments, so how would I do that if i have no instance variables, am used to creating a constructor where i have instance variables, I know java creates a default constructor if i don't have one but i was told that is a bad programming practice???(new to classes)

```
public class Validator {
    public Validator() {
    }

    public String getString(Scanner sc, String prompt) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        String s = sc.next(); // read user entry
        sc.nextLine(); // discard any other data entered on the line
        return s;
    }

    public int getInt(Scanner sc, String prompt) {
        int i = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false) {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                i = sc.nextInt();
                isValid = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error! Invalid integer value. Try again.");
            }
            sc.nextLine(); // discard any other data entered on the line
        }
        return i;
    }

    public int getInt(Scanner sc, String prompt, int min, int max) {
        int i = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false) {
            i = getInt(sc, prompt);
            if (i <= min)
                System.out.println("Error! Number must be greater than " + min
                        + ".");
            else if (i >= max)
                System.out.println("Error! Number must be less than " + max
                        + ".");
            else
                isValid = true;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public double getDouble(Scanner sc, String prompt) {
        double d = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false) {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                d = sc.nextDouble();
                isValid = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error! Invalid decimal value. Try again.");
            }
            sc.nextLine(); // discard any other data entered on the line
        }
        return d;
    }

    public double getDouble(Scanner sc, String prompt, double min, double max) {
        double d = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false) {
            d = getDouble(sc, prompt);
            if (d <= min)
                System.out.println("Error! Number must be greater than " + min
                        + ".");
            else if (d >= max)
                System.out.println("Error! Number must be less than " + max
                        + ".");
            else
                isValid = true;
        }
        return d;
    }
}
```

Comment: how is all code after the constructor relevant to your question?

Comment: If there is nothing to do in your constructor, then you don't need to declare one.

Comment: Someone I know was learning programming recently, too. His teaching material said "Always create getters and setters" but he never stopped to ask why he needed them. Now he's exposing private variables and hiding public. When you design objects, try to go with "Object oriented philosophy" more than general rules of specific parts. Does the dog need to know what sound the cat makes? Maybe so, but does it need to know the internal state of the cat's hunger also? Probably not. Constructors would follow similar points

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A constructor is used to "build" an object. If you have no values that you need to set, then there is no need for a constructor. You might also want to consider making your class [static](http://dadicy.wordpress.com/2007/10/29/what-do-you-mean-by-static-in-java/). Static means you don't need to create an instance of it to access it's methods. This is often useful when the instance of the class contains no specific values, much like yours!

Comment: what would the java default constructor look like for my code above??

Comment: The default Java constructor is generated for you by the JVM. You don't need to write anything :)

Answer (score 3):

If there are no instance variables and no other required tasks to initialize an object of your class, you can leave out the constructor. The Java compiler will provide a default one for you. Typically I only include an explicit constructor when I know exactly what I need it to do.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to explicitly define a constructor. There is already a default constructor. And it's not at all a bad programming practice to make use of that constructor.